# If condition based on string read from Database

Tags: vb.net

I want to have an If condition based on a condition obtained from a database.  So each row in this table has a condition as a string on when something should be displayed.

Example: the row has the column "DisplayWhen" with the value "Status="M"".

The syntax of the condition statement is vb.net and the variable "Status" is available in the code.

So my statement is:

```
If CBool(rdr.Item("DisplayWhen").tostring.trim) then
    'something 
End If
```

But I keep getting the error: Conversion from string "Status="M"" to type Boolean is not valid.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to compare the data you got to the value you expect. A string is not a bool rdr.Item(DisplayWhen).toString.trim = "M" is.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment a string in itself can not evaluated to a Boolean, you need to compare it to your expected value. Something like this.

```
If CBool(rdr.Item("DisplayWhen").ToString.Trim = "Status=""M""") Then
    'something 
End If
```

or using the Equals Method

```
If rdr.Item("DisplayWhen").Equals("Status=""M""") Then
   'something
End If
```

Comment: I understand what your saying, but the problem is the expected "condition" I want to pull from the table.  It could be color="Red" for one record, but height>10 for the next one.

Comment: If you are using an If statement you have to know what you are comparing to at the time that you do the comparison, Just use that as your condition.